# How to make a pagination into a (show more)button in cakephp2?

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to cakephp2 and I need some help here.

The problem is that I have a view that displays a list of items from the database and there is a pagination button below. Instead of moving to the 2nd page by using the pagination, I want to have a single button that will allow you to display(append)10 more data list. But I'm not sure how it is called and how to implement it. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can play with limit parameter.
Somethink like this:

```
// in controller
<?php
function items() {
   $limit = array_key_exists('n', $this->request->query) ? (int) $this->request->query['n'] : 10;

   // some security check you need to add

   $this->paginate = array(
      'limit' => $limit
   );
   $items = $this->paginate($this->YourModel);

   // some other code

   $this->set(array(
      'items' => $items,
      'next_limit' => $limit + 10
   ));
}
?>

<?php
// in view file

// items output
foreach($items as $item) ...

// more button
echo "<a href='".$this->here."?n=".$next_limit."'>More</a>";
?>
```